# Why is this double switch controlling both light circuits from both switches?

Tags: electrical

My house has a double switch that is controlling 2 different lights (A and B). However, when I turn either one of the switches on, both lights turn on. Can somebody explain to me why this isn't working as expected?

I drew a diagram showing how it is wired. I am really confused because it should work as it is... Oh, and all 4 of the red twist caps are actually in the same box.

[image]

Comment: "Can somebody explain to me why this isn't working as expected?" How it is supposed to work and how you expect it to work may not be the same. **How do you expect it to work ?**

Comment: I expect switch A to control light A and switch B to control light B.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You disregarded a feature these switches have, where one side of both switches are wired together.   They can be separated by breaking a tab, but you didn't.

[image]

<sub>[source](https://publicism.info/engineering/wiring/5.html)</sub>

This side is intended to be the "common" side, so you could accomplish the left side of your diagram with one wire. However you placed it on the right side,  where it shorts the output of both switches.

Just rewire to suit, or break off the tab.

Comment: Thank you! That worked! I ended up rewiring it instead of breaking the tab.